# Error Starting Ruby on Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run a ruby on rails application on my system locally but when executing the rails server command I'm getting the following error:

```
/Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/carlossosa/honda/documentolegal2/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activerecord-3.2.18/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:80:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/carlossosa/honda/documentolegal2/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/carlossosa/honda/documentolegal2/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/carlossosa/honda/documentolegal2/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/carlossosa/honda/documentolegal2/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:304:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:254:in `start'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/carlossosa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/railties-3.2.18/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the `documentolegal2/config/database.yml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are missing a database configuration file

```
#{project_root}/config/database.yml
```

You will need to create one. You can find the information on how to set it up in the link down below:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. But now I'm getting a new Error